# can't override the CSS :root variable | --primary-color: orange; does not respond

Tags: css, variables, overriding

This is my 'root':

```
:root {

--primary-color: #B92430;
}
```

But I can't override it in subsequent classes:

```
h1 {

--primary-color: orange;
font-family: 'New Tegomin', sans-serif;

}
```

The h1 class does not respond to the variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you have defined (and redefined) what the variable is, you haven't stated what property it should apply to. Here I assume you mean `color`.

```css
:root {
  --primary-color: green;
}

h1.change {
  --primary-color: red;
  color: var(--primary-color);
}
```

```html
<h1 class="change">Lorem, ipsum.</h1>
```